# I cannot reach to variable declared outside of mongodb function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, variables, var, console.log

Title says it all I tried it all but variable just returns undefined at console.log

```
var kategorilerArray;
dbo.collection("anasayfaKategoriler").find().sort(mysort).toArray(function (err, resultKategoriler) {
    if (err) throw err;
    kategorilerArray = resultKategoriler;
    //console.log(kategorilerArray);
});
console.log(kategorilerArray); // > undefined
```

Comment: does toArray take a callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are logging undefined is because this is how JS work, meaning that line of code will happen before the kategorilerArray assignment.
that line will run before the callback (toArray function receives that callback) and only then the assignment to kategorilerArray will happen.

you can fix it by adding the kategorilerArray assignment inside the toArray callback function or await the toArray function and then make the assignment.

This is part of the JS event loop.

you can read more about it in this article:
https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-event-loop-and-the-rise-of-async-programming-5-ways-to-better-coding-with-2f077c4438b5

Comment: thank you sir, I fixed it with inserting await.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, just declare express app.post async

```
var yorumlarArray = await dbo.collection("yorumlar").find().sort(mysort).toArray();
var kategorilerArray = await dbo.collection("anasayfaKategoriler").find().sort(mysort).toArray();
console.log(kategorilerArray);
```